# Checking parameters of multiplication by constant in 64 bit

Tags: delphi, x86-64, basm

For my BigInteger code, output turned out to be slow for very large BigIntegers. So now I use a recursive divide-and-conquer algorithm, which still needs 2'30" to convert the currently largest known prime to a decimal string of more than 22 million digits (but only 135 ms to turn it into a hexadecimal string).

I still want to reduce the time, so I need a routine that can divide a NativeUInt (i.e. UInt32 on 32 bit platforms, UInt64 on 64 bit platforms) by 100 very fast. So I use multiplication by constant. This works fine in 32 bit code, but I am not 100% sure for 64 bit.

So my question: is there a way to check the reliability of the results of multiplication by constant for unsigned 64 bit values? I checked the 32 bit values by simply trying with all values of UInt32 (0..$FFFFFFFF). This took approx. 3 minutes. Checking all UInt64s would take much longer than my lifetime. Is there a way to check if the parameters used (constant, post-shift) are reliable?

I noticed that `DivMod100()` always failed for a value like `$4000004B` if the chosen parameters were wrong (but close). Are there special values or ranges to check for 64 bit, so I don't have to check *all* values?

My current code:

```
const
{$IF DEFINED(WIN32)}
  // Checked
  Div100Const = UInt32(UInt64($1FFFFFFFFF) div 100 + 1);
  Div100PostShift = 5;
{$ELSEIF DEFINED(WIN64)}
  // Unchecked!!
  Div100Const = $A3D70A3D70A3D71; 
  // UInt64(UInt128($3 FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF) div 100 + 1); 
  // UInt128 is fictive type.
  Div100PostShift = 2;
{$IFEND}

// Calculates X div 100 using multiplication by a constant, taking the
// high part of the 64 bit (or 128 bit) result and shifting
// right. The remainder is calculated as X - quotient * 100;
// This was tested to work safely and quickly for all values of UInt32.
function DivMod100(var X: NativeUInt): NativeUInt;
{$IFDEF WIN32}
asm
        // EAX = address of X, X is UInt32 here.
        PUSH    EBX
        MOV     EDX,Div100Const
        MOV     ECX,EAX
        MOV     EAX,[ECX]
        MOV     EBX,EAX
        MUL     EDX
        SHR     EDX,Div100PostShift
        MOV     [ECX],EDX       // Quotient

        // Slightly faster than MUL

        LEA     EDX,[EDX + 4*EDX] // EDX := EDX * 5;
        LEA     EDX,[EDX + 4*EDX] // EDX := EDX * 5;
        SHL     EDX,2             // EDX := EDX * 4; 5*5*4 = 100.

        MOV     EAX,EBX
        SUB     EAX,EDX         // Remainder
        POP     EBX
end;
{$ELSE WIN64}
asm
        .NOFRAME

        // RCX is address of X, X is UInt64 here.
        MOV     RAX,[RCX]
        MOV     R8,RAX
        XOR     RDX,RDX
        MOV     R9,Div100Const
        MUL     R9
        SHR     RDX,Div100PostShift
        MOV     [RCX],RDX      // Quotient

        // Faster than LEA and SHL

        MOV     RAX,RDX
        MOV     R9D,100
        MUL     R9
        SUB     R8,RAX
        MOV     RAX,R8         // Remainder
end;
{$ENDIF WIN32}
```

Comment: This is close to a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270596/ but in any case you'll find the answer there by reading libdivide

Comment: I used libdivide to generate a constant, but it amounts to `$1C0000000000000000 div 100 + 1` with a post-shift of 6, but the result is not `n div 100` in the high part. libdivide gives the results I expect for 32 bit, but perhaps I don't understand the way it is used for 64 bit. I'll experiment a little more.

Comment: Please provide an answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Ok, I found how to do it properly, using libdivide.h. Apparently there is a shift/add step required. Works fine now. Should I post the solution as an answer, or just edit the question?

Comment: OK, will post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual when writing optimized code, use compiler output for hints / starting points.  It's safe to assume any optimization it makes is safe in the general case.  Wrong-code compiler bugs are rare.

gcc implements unsigned 64bit divmod with a constant of `0x28f5c28f5c28f5c3`.  I haven't looked in detail into generating constants for division, but there are algorithms for generating them that will give known-good results (so exhaustive testing isn't needed).

The code actually has a few important differences: it uses the constant differently from the OP's constant.

See the comments for an analysis of what this is is actually doing: divide by 4 first, so it can use a constant that only works for dividing by 25 when the dividend is small enough.  This also avoids needing an add at all, later on.

```c
#include <stdint.h>

// rem, quot ordering takes one extra instruction
struct divmod { uint64_t quotient, remainder; }
 div_by_100(uint64_t x) {
    struct divmod retval = { x%100, x/100 };
    return retval;
}
```

[compiles to (gcc 5.3 `-O3 -mtune=haswell`)](http://goo.gl/VjHQDy):

```
    movabs  rdx, 2951479051793528259
    mov     rax, rdi            ; Function arg starts in RDI (SysV ABI)
    shr     rax, 2
    mul     rdx
    shr     rdx, 2
    lea     rax, [rdx+rdx*4]    ; multiply by 5
    lea     rax, [rax+rax*4]    ; multiply by another 5
    sal     rax, 2              ; imul rax, rdx, 100 is better here (Intel SnB).
    sub     rdi, rax
    mov     rax, rdi
    ret
; return values in rdx:rax
```

Use the "binary" option to see the constant in hex, since disassembler output does it that way, unlike gcc's asm source output.

---

#### The multiply-by-100 part.

gcc uses the above sequence of lea/lea/shl, the same as in your question.  Your answer is using a `mov imm`/`mul` sequence.

Your comments each say the version they chose is faster.  If so, it's because of some subtle instruction alignment or other secondary effect:  On Intel SnB-family, it's [the same number of uops (3)](http://agner.org/optimize/), and the same critical-path latency (`mov imm` is off the critical path, and `mul` is 3 cycles).

[clang uses](http://goo.gl/dDV267) what I think is the best bet (`imul rax, rdx, 100`).  I thought of it before I saw that clang chose it, not that that matters.  That's 1 fused-domain uop (which can execute on p0 only), still with 3c latency.  So if you're latency-bound using this routine for multi-precision, it probably won't help, but it is the best choice.  (If you're latency-bound, inlining your code into a loop instead of passing one of the parameters through memory could save a lot of cycles.)

`imul` works because [you're only using the low 64b of the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377711/which-2s-complement-integer-operations-can-be-used-without-zeroing-high-bits-in).  There's no 2 or 3 operand form of `mul` because the low half of the result is the same regardless of signed or unsigned interpretation of the inputs.

BTW, clang with `-march=native` uses `mulx` for the 64x64->128, instead of `mul`, but doesn't gain anything by it.  According to Agner Fog's tables, it's one cycle worse latency than `mul`.

---

AMD has worse than 3c latency for `imul r,r,i` (esp. the 64b version), which is maybe why gcc avoids it.  IDK how much work gcc maintainers put into tweaking costs so settings like `-mtune=haswell` work well, but a *lot* of code isn't compiled with any `-mtune` setting (even one implied by `-march`), so I'm not surprised when gcc makes choices that were optimal for older CPUs, or for AMD.

clang still uses `imul r64, r64, imm` with `-mtune=bdver1` (Bulldozer), which saves m-ops but at a cost of 1c latency more than using lea/lea/shl.  (lea with a scale>1 is 2c latency on Bulldozer).

Comment: @user246408: If I'm following the comments on your answer correct, clang and gcc probably do it this way so they don't need a 65bit add-and-shift, right?  This does look cheaper than than Rudy's code.

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted my comments; because I did not look enough into the gcc code; yes, it uses only shift, not add-and-shift; the constant `0x28f5c28f5c28f5c3` is the same most signicant bits of reciprocal of 1/25 (or 1/100, they are the same), only bit-shifted right by 2 bits. Given the gcc code is correct, it uses optimization based on the the fact that the dividend after preshifting right 2 bits is less than 0x4000000000000000. Summing up: though general 64-bit constant for division by 25 does not exist, it exists for dividends less than 0x4000000000000000.

Comment: @user246408: thanks for that analysis.  I didn't take the time to grok the whole picture, I mostly just wanted to contribute a "look what the compiler does" answer, without taking the time to understand exactly why the compiler was able to do that.

Comment: Would be nice if you add the gcc code for `div_by_25`. If my analysis is correct, it should be different from `div_by_100` because add-and-shift thing is needed.

Comment: @user246408: godbolt makes it super-easy for anyone to go and try code changes and see the same asm output that I copy/pasted.  That's why I put godbolt links in all my asm-output answers.  Anyway, here's a link with [div_by_100 and div_by_25](http://goo.gl/z3Bn05).  You're right, it shifts by one and adds.  The constant it uses is `0x47ae147ae147ae15`, to save the trouble of flipping godbolt to "binary" mode to get hex.  Interestingly, ICC13 uses that constant for both `div_by_100` and `div_by_25`.  Instead of multiplying by 25 or 100, it multiplies by `-25` or `-100`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with [libdivide.h](https://raw.github.com/ridiculousfish/libdivide/master/libdivide.h). Here is the slightly more complicated part for Win64:

```
{$ELSE WIN64}
asm
        .NOFRAME

        MOV     RAX,[RCX]
        MOV     R8,RAX
        XOR     RDX,RDX
        MOV     R9,Div100Const       // New: $47AE147AE147AE15
        MUL     R9                   // Preliminary result Q in RDX

        // Additional part: add/shift

        ADD     RDX,R8               // Q := Q + X shr 1;
        RCR     RDX,1

        SHR     RDX,Div100PostShift  // Q := Q shr 6;
        MOV     [RCX],RDX            // X := Q;

        // Faster than LEA and SHL

        MOV     RAX,RDX
        MOV     R9D,100
        MUL     R9
        SUB     R8,RAX
        MOV     RAX,R8         // Remainder
end;
{$ENDIF WIN32}
```

Comment: Why not `(Q + X) shr 1` instead of `Q + (X - Q) shr 1`?

Comment: Hmmm... I took this from libdivide.h. I guess the intermediate result might overflow, for some values. I can try, though. If necessary, I can try to use `RCR` instead. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @user246408: You are right. I used RCR to shift back in the carry in case of an overflow, and it is slightly simpler and faster now. I edited the answer.

Comment: Interesting trick with `rcr` to get an extra bit of intermediate precision.  It's a 3 uop instruction on Intel SnB-family, (replacing three 1uop insns) so the change doesn't save any uops there.  It's only 1 m-op on AMD, though, so it saves two macro-ops there.  Note that `rcr` by an immediate count other than 1 is significantly slower, so it's not useful even if you could combine its right-shift with the following `shr`.  `rcr` is 2c latency (Intel), and the `mov` wasn't on the critical path (and is zero latency anyway on IvB and later), so again it's a wash.  (sub and shl r,1 are 1c)

Comment: @PeterCordes: So `MOV R9,R8; SUB R9,RDX; SHR R9,1; ADD RDX,R9` is equivalent (qua timing, I mean -- I know it gives the same result) to the above while it avoids the "65th bit"?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: on Intel SnB-family, yes same uop count and latency.  Maybe different port requirements.  (e.g. IvB and later don't need a port for the mov).  On Pentium-M to Nehalem, it's 2 uops (still with 2c latency).  On AMD (and PII/PIII), the `add` / `rcr 1` is faster.  On Silvermont, `rcr 1` is 7uops (while simple instructions are still 1).  I've seen the `Q + (X - Q)/2` idiom before, in C, for calculating an average while avoiding overflow/carry.  Anyway, you've stumbled onto another one of those "faster on one CPU, slower on others" cases.

Comment: You don't need to zero `rdx` before `mul`.  It's a write-only operand for `mul`, unlike `div`.  And like I pointed out in my answer, `imul rax, rdx, 100` is better than `lea` / `lea` / `shl`.  [clang even uses it](http://goo.gl/dDV267).  Clang's version is 9 uops (Intel Haswell) to your 12 (not counting your loads and stores or the wasted xor).

Comment: ^Yes. There are 2 improvements possible: (1) instead of zeroing `RDX` move the `Div100Const` in `RDX` and `MUL RDX`; (2) if `RCR` is slow then shift the dividend 1 (or 2) bits right and divide by 50 (or 25) - there would be no overflow so no need for `RCR`.

Comment: @user and Peter: I keep forgetting that I don't have to zero out RDX before a mult, only before I start a division chain.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the @Rudy's answer results from the following steps:

1. Write 1/100 in binary form: `0.000000(10100011110101110000)`;
2. Count leading zeroes after the decimal point: `S = 6`;
3. 72 first significant bits are:

`1010 0011 1101 0111 0000 1010 0011 1101 0111 0000 1010 0011 1101 0111 0000 1010 0011 1101`

4. Round to 65 bits; there is some kind of magic in how this rounding is performed; by reverse-engineering the constant from the Rudy's answer the correct rounding is:

`1010 0011 1101 0111 0000 1010 0011 1101 0111 0000 1010 0011 1101 0111 0000 1010 1`

5. Remove the leading `1` bit:

`0100 0111 1010 1110 0001 0100 0111 1010 1110 0001 0100 0111 1010 1110 0001 0101`

6. Write in hexadecimal form (getting back the revenged constant):

`A = 47 AE 14 7A E1 47 AE 15`

7. `X div 100 = (((uint128(X) * uint128(A)) shr 64) +  X) shr 7` `(7 = 1 + S)`

---

Comment: I actually did something similar for 32 bit, but simpler. I divided `$100000000` by `100` (I actually started with `div 25` and then `shr 2`), and tried this with all cardinals. When that did not succeed, I used `$200000000` and one shift extra, and repeated this until I found what I needed.

Comment: FWIW, the rounding used seems to be quite simple: round up (away from zero). But why is the leading one bit removed? I still think that `magic = $3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF div 100 + 1` (you have that too: `$A3D70A3... etc.`) and a shift of 6 should work too. I just don't know how to prove or test it reliably.

Comment: FWIW, their constant is `$1C0000000000000000 div 100`, mine is `$400000000000000000 div 100`. $1C = 28. So that is (28/64) * (64/100) = 28/100. Add to that 100/100 (X) and you have 128/100th of X. Shift that right once, and you have 64/100th. Shift that right 6 times and you get 1/100th. ISTM that my constant (`$A3D70...`) should work without the add/shift and give the exact same result. Also note that 64bit x 64bit can never overflow into 129 bits or some such, so there is no need for trickery like (Q + (X - Q) shr 1).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  the leading 1 bit is removed because it is accounted by adding `X` in the final formula; the trick of adding `X` means that we use 65-bit constant instead of 64-bit as you tried in you first attempt; 64-bit constant is not enough to produce always correct division result in 64-bit case; I also not sure that 65-bit constant is enough in 64-bit case.

Comment: Hmmm... a 32 bit constant is good enough to reliably get the correct result in 32 bit. Perhaps not for all values, but apparently for div 100. I understood that X is added in.

Comment: FWIW, instead of 100, I could use 25 for division and then shift right by 2 later on. That would avoid the 65th bit and would allow an even more accurate constant. I'll have to try that.

Comment: Hmmm... libdivide gives the same constant value and code and only a shift of 4 instead of 6 for division by 25. Nothing gained.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - looks like 65 bits is always enough; actually (N+1)-bit constant is always enough for N-bit division, while N-bit constant is possible for some divisors only.

Comment: I'm currently reading this. That seems to be the base for the libdivide code: https://gmplib.org/~tege/divcnst-pldi94.pdf

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - Have read with this article, some thoughts: https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/integer-division-by-constant/